# Django request GET return None on string

Tags: django, django-views

I have this url :

```
   /page_b/a015541/?pagei=a011&account_id=95651&application_id=5563&startdate=20170101&enddate=20170101
```

When parsing with :

```
   page_id=         request.GET.get('pagename')
   account_id=         request.GET.get('account_id')
   application_id=  request.GET.get('application_id')
   uurid=  request.GET.get('uurid')
```

I have for string values :
    page_id = None

Numerical have correct values

How to fix this ?

Comment: you are not sending pagename in URL.  Seems you are sending `pagei` in URL

Comment: `page_id = request.GET.get('pagei')` will get you `a011`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to URL

```
/page_b/a015541/?pagei=a011&account_id=95651&application_id=5563&startdate=20170101&enddate=20170101
```

You are sending `pagei`.

just replace

```
page_id=         request.GET.get('pagename')
```

with

```
page_id=         request.GET.get('pagei')
```

you will get page_id

Answer (score 1):

In URL you are not sending 'pagename'. I think you are trying to get 'pagei'.

That case use like below.

```
request.GET.get('pagei')
```

Comment: what's the new in your answer? As this is already told in one answer?